# How to link this menubar into this div content using javascript or jquery...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently when you click on a div box it goes to left on screen and next div box is coming to screen from right. what is need is, clicking the menu links to scroll to the corresponding div container. E.g clicking link 5 scrolls to div #5 Can anyone help me with it...? It would be a big help guys.

HTML

```
<ul class="btns">
        <li><a href="#" rel="box1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="box2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="box3">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="box4">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="box5">5</a></li>           
    </ul>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="box1" class="box">Div #1</div>
        <div id="box2" class="box">Div #2</div>
        <div id="box3" class="box">Div #3</div>
        <div id="box4" class="box">Div #4</div>
        <div id="box5" class="box">Div #5</div>

    </div>​
```

Javascript and Jquery part:

```
$('.btns>li a').click(function() {
                var page = $(this).attr('rel');
            });                


            $('.box').click(function() {
                $('.box').each( function() {
                    if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
                        $(this).css("left", "150%");
                    }
                });

                $(this).animate({
                    left: '-50%'
                }, 500);

                if ($(this).next().size() > 0) {
                    $(this).next().animate({
                        left: '50%'
                    }, 500);
                } else {
                    $(this).prevAll().last().animate({
                        left: '50%'
                    }, 500);
                }
            });​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gHYSN/5/

Comment: What do you mean by "link these div boxes with the menubar"?

Comment: I believe he wants clicking the links to scroll to the corresponding div container. E.g clicking link 5 scrolls to div #5.

Comment: @ Justin: yes you are right. I need to do that. Can you guys help me..?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this might not be the best method out there, but it is working as required.

```
function swdiv(currID, nxtID) {
    $('.box').each(function() {
        if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
            $(this).css("left", "150%");
        }
    });
    $('#' + currID).animate({
        left: '-50%'
    }, 500);
    if ($('#' + nxtID).size() > 0) {
        $('#' + nxtID).animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 500);
    }
}

$('.btns li a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('rel'),
        curID = 'box1',
        iWide = $(window).width() / 2;
    $('.box').each(function() {
        if ($(this).css('left') == iWide + 'px') {
            curID = $(this).attr('id');
        }
    });
    swdiv(curID, page);
});
$('.box').click(function() {
    $('.box').each(function() {
        if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
            $(this).css("left", "150%");
        }
    });
    $(this).animate({
        left: '-50%'
    }, 500);
    if ($(this).next().size() > 0) {
        $(this).next().animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 500);
    } else {
        $(this).prevAll().last().animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

I've created an extra function to switch between two `div`s. Check it on the 8th update on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gHYSN/8/).

Comment: yes it's working as i expected but there's a little bug in there. I'll try to work on it. I'll keep this question little bit longer to get some good ideas..

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test this, but I think it should give you the basic idea.

```
$(".btns a").each(function(index, a) {
    $(a).click(function() {
        var boxnum = index + 1;
        $(window).scrollTop($("#box" + boxnum).offset().top);
    });
}
```